# Regex: match and replace two groups at once

Tags: javascript, regex

How to find find groups of uppercase and lowercase characters in a string and replace them this way:

- add html tags for upper case groups: `<span class="upper_group">FOO</span>`
- add html tags for lower case groups and transform to uppercase: `<span class="lower_group">BAR</span>`

I tried this below, but can't transform the lower groups easily to upper case:

```
let sentence = "NOCH KEt SKUIZh";

let newSentence = sentence.replace(/([a-z]+)/g, '<span class="bar">$1</span>').replace(/([A-Z'.]+)/g, "<span class='foo'>$1</span>");
```

Expected output:

```
<span class="foo">NOCH</span> <span class="foo">KE</span><span class="bar">t</span> <span class="foo">SKUIZ</span><span class="bar">h</span>
```

Comment: @anubhava I've just updated my post to show the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let sentence = "NOCH KEt SKUIZh";

let newSentence = sentence.replace(/([a-z]+)|([A-Z'.]+)/g, (a,b) => b ? `<span class="adlavaret2">${a.toUpperCase()}</span>` : `<span class="adlavaret1">${a}</span>`);

console.log(newSentence);
```

Comment: I would be nice for future readers to add a bit of an explanation to the answer instead of only code.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider this code:

```js
var s = "NOCH KEt SKUIZh";

var r = s.replace(/([a-z]+)|([A-Z]+)/g,
   (m, g1, g2) => '<span class="' + (g1 != undefined ? 'lower">' + g1  : 'upper">' + g2) + '</span>');

console.log(r);

//=> '<span class="upper">NOCH</span> <span class="upper">KE</span><span class="lower">t</span> <span class="upper">SKUIZ</span><span class="lower">h</span>'
```

**RegEx+lamnda Details:**

- `([a-z]+)`: Matches 1+ lowercase letters in in 1st group
- `|`: or
- `([A-Z]+)`: Matches 1+ uppercase letters in in 2nd group
- `(m, g1, g2)`: Makes available `m` (full match) and `gN` (Nth capture group) to lambda expression
- When `g1` is not null then use class `lower` otherwise use class `upper`

Answer (score 2):

The following assumes your expected output should really be:

`<span class="foo">NOCH</span> <span class="foo">KE</span><span class="bar">T</span> <span class="foo">SKUIZ</span><span class="bar">H</span>`

You can use a replacer function. For example:

```js
let sentence = "NOCH KEt SKUIZh";

let replacer = (_, g1, g2) =>
  `<span class="${ g1 ? `foo">${g1}` : `bar">${g2.toUpperCase()}` }</span>`;

let newSentence = sentence.replace(/([A-Z]+)|([a-z]+)/g, replacer);

console.log(newSentence);
```

The `g1` is the string captured by the `([A-Z]+)` and the `g2` is the string captured by the `([a-z]+)`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getUpperLowerSubstitute(match, upper, lower) {
  return (
    (upper && `<span class="upper_group">${ upper }</span>`) ||
    (lower && `<span class="lower_group">${ lower }</span>`) ||
    ''
  );
}
const regXUpperLower = /(?<upper>[[A-Z]+)|(?<lower>[[a-z]+)/g

console.log(
  '"NOCH KEt SKUIZh".replace(regXUpperLower, getUpperLowerSubstitute) ...',
  "NOCH KEt SKUIZh".replace(regXUpperLower, getUpperLowerSubstitute)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```